# How to create loop to construct all 52 cards in a complete deck?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two different js files, one for the card constructor and the other for the deck. I am trying to create the load function for the deck object so i can load 52 card objects all unique to create a complete deck but im not sure how to make the loop to do so.

card.js

```
function card(pRank, pSuit){
    this.rank = pRank,
    this.suit = pSuit,
    this.used = false;
}
```

deck.js

```
deck = {

    cardArray: [],

    load: function(){
        for(i=0; i<52; i++){
           this.cardArray.push(card);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `rank` and `suit`? An integer 0 to 12 and 0 to 3? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If structure is next you can do following

```
const ranks = ['ACE', 'KING', 'QUEEN', 'JACK', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2'];
const suits = ['SPADES', 'HEARTS', 'DIAMONDS', 'CLUBS'];

function card(pRank, pSuit){
    this.rank = pRank,
    this.suit = pSuit,
    this.used = false;
}

const cardArray = suits.reduce((cards, suit) => { return [
        ...cards,
        ...ranks.map((rank) => new card(suit, rank))
    ]
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

easily Understandable code.

```js
var ranks = ['ACE', 'KING', 'QUEEN', 'JACK', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2'];
var suits = ['SPADES', 'HEARTS', 'DIAMONDS', 'CLUBS'];
var cards = [];
var m = 0;
var finalDeck = suits.map(function(i, j) {
  return ranks.map(function(k, l) {
    return new card(k,i)
  })
})

function card(pRank, pSuit) {
  this.rank = pRank,
    this.suit = pSuit,
    this.used = false;
}

console.log(finalDeck)
```